# expand panel data and get a running year as a column

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a data frame which I want to expand like a panel data.

```
 profile<- c('lehman', 'john','oliver','stephen','picasso')
 from<-   c(2008, 2008,2009,2008,2009)
 to <-   c (2009, 2009, 2009, 2009,2009)
 df<- data.frame(profile, from, to)
```

I want to create an additional row called year (running year) which would be as follows. I mean the data is expanded as the difference between from year and end year (and 2009 is the default end year). So I want to have two rows for the from year with 2008 and 1 row for 2009. Any suggestions?

```
 profile from   to   year
 lehman  2008 2009   2008
 lehman  2009 2009   2009
 john    2008 2009   2008
 john    2008 2009   2009
 oliver  2009 2009   2009
 stephen 2008 2009   2008
 stephen 2008 2009   2009
 picasso 2009 2009   2009
```

Comment: You mean an additional column? Where does the data in column year come from?

Comment: I mean the data is expanded as the difference between from year and end year (and 2009 is the default end year). So I want to have two rows for the from year with 2008 and 1 row for 2009.

Comment: Something like `library(tidyverse); df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(year = list(seq(from, to))) %>% unnest()`

Comment: I am getting this error. Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements. Can you advise?

Comment: I think you need to `ungroup()` before `unnest()`, but I can't check right now because my dplyr installation is all messed up at the moment.

Comment: it worked, i had to remove all the lists elements from the data frame for that

Comment: If you have other list columns, specify the column you want to unnest and set `.drop = FALSE`. In some cases this could suddenly make a data.frame really big, though, so use with caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list column and `unnest` to expand, duplicating the other variables as necessary:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% rowwise() %>%    # calculate seq separately for each row
    mutate(year = list(seq(from, to))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    unnest()
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   profile  from    to  year
#>    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1  lehman  2008  2009  2008
#> 2  lehman  2008  2009  2009
#> 3    john  2008  2009  2008
#> 4    john  2008  2009  2009
#> 5  oliver  2009  2009  2009
#> 6 stephen  2008  2009  2008
#> 7 stephen  2008  2009  2009
#> 8 picasso  2009  2009  2009
```